# Environment.ts | Ionic | Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, environment

Buenas tardes.
Es mi primer mes de programador y haciendo algunas tareas me surgio una duda.
Es buena practica aplicar logica en el archivo **environment.ts**?
Es aconsejable?
o si me es funcional, no importaria? que opinan?

esto fue lo que hice. Mi PM me dijo que no sabia, pero al ser funcional lo dejamos asi. Pero me gustaria la opinion de expertos y de la comunidad.
Obviamente las ultimas lineas de condicionales son las que agregue para que funcione. Lo que pasaba era que al refrescar la app, si estabas en la baseUrlMX, se me pisaba la baseUrl original que era la de argentina y fallaba la app. Entonces se me ocurrio esta solucion. Cada vez que se usa el archivo environment ese condicional vuelve a setear la base url como corresponde.

```
const baseUrlApiAr = "https://demo-api..io/";
const baseUrlApiMx = "https://api-mx.io/";
const baseUrlApiBr = "https://api-br..io/";
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  api: {
    baseUrlApi: baseUrlApiAr,
    baseUrlImages: `${baseUrlApiAr}upload/`,
    baseUrlApiAr: baseUrlApiAr,
    baseUrlApiMx: baseUrlApiMx,
    baseUrlApiBr: baseUrlApiBr,
    baseUrlImagesAr: `${baseUrlApiAr}upload/`,
    baseUrlImagesMx: `${baseUrlApiMx}upload/`,
    baseUrlImagesBr: `${baseUrlApiBr}upload/`,
    client_id: '8_5p05iv500wsws4oco',
    client_secret: '500s88wso0g',
  },
}
if(localStorage.getItem('codeCountry')==="AR"){
  environment.api.baseUrlApi = environment.api.baseUrlApiAr;
  environment.api.baseUrlImages = environment.api.baseUrlImagesAr; 
}if(localStorage.getItem('codeCountry')==="MX"){
  environment.api.baseUrlApi = environment.api.baseUrlApiMx;
  environment.api.baseUrlImages = environment.api.baseUrlImagesMx; 
}if(localStorage.getItem('codeCountry')==="BR"){
  environment.api.baseUrlImages = environment.api.baseUrlImagesBr; 
  environment.api.baseUrlApi = environment.api.baseUrlApiBr;
};
```

Que opinan?? GRACIAS!!!

Comment: yo pondría la lógica en una función para no tenerlo desordenado y llamarla desde el enviroment porque en algunas versiones de angular no te podría funcionar dejarlo por fuera

Answer (score 1):

yo pondría la lógica en una función para no tenerlo desordenado y llamarla desde el enviroment porque en algunas versiones de angular no te podría funcionar dejarlo por fuera

```
export const environment = {


production: false,
  api: {
    baseUrlApi: baseUrlApiAr,
    valid:validaURL()
    baseUrlImages: `${baseUrlApiAr}upload/`,
    baseUrlApiAr: baseUrlApiAr,
    baseUrlApiMx: baseUrlApiMx,
    baseUrlApiBr: baseUrlApiBr,
    baseUrlImagesAr: `${baseUrlApiAr}upload/`,
    baseUrlImagesMx: `${baseUrlApiMx}upload/`,
    baseUrlImagesBr: `${baseUrlApiBr}upload/`,
    client_id: '8_5p05iv500wsws4oco',
    client_secret: '500s88wso0g',
  },
}
validaURL(){
 if(localStorage.getItem('codeCountry')==="AR"){
  environment.api.baseUrlApi = environment.api.baseUrlApiAr;
  environment.api.baseUrlImages = environment.api.baseUrlImagesAr; 
 }if(localStorage.getItem('codeCountry')==="MX"){
  environment.api.baseUrlApi = environment.api.baseUrlApiMx;
  environment.api.baseUrlImages = environment.api.baseUrlImagesMx; 
 }if(localStorage.getItem('codeCountry')==="BR"){
  environment.api.baseUrlImages = environment.api.baseUrlImagesBr; 
  environment.api.baseUrlApi = environment.api.baseUrlApiBr;
 };
}
```

Comment: Bien! me gusta la idea! muchas gracias Wiliiam